# Spring Boot with QueryDSL and Pagination: Page-Sorting on nested Array-Element do not work

Tags: java, spring, sorting, pagination, querydsl

I use Spring Boot QueryDSL to filter my entities and the Spring Boot-Page-Feature for Pagination and Sorting , so that I can  invoke following method:

```
Page<Country> all=countryRepository.findAll(predicate,pageable);
```

Now lets say with following query I want to filter all Countries where its collected translation Objects have a languageid with "de":

```
http://localhost:8090/countries?translations.languages.id=de
```

I get following result:

```
 [
        {
            "id": "DE",
            "currency": "EUR",  
            "preSelection": 49,
            "currencySign": "€",
            "translations": [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "name": "Deutschland",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "de"
                },
                {
                    "id": "322",
                    "name": "Allemagne",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "fr"
                },
                {
                    "id": "18",
                    "name": "Germany",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "en"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "ES",  
            "currency": "EUR",
            "preSelection": 34, 
            "currencySign": "€",
            "translations": [
                {
                    "id": "16",
                    "name": "Spanien",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "de"
                },
                {
                    "id": "23",
                    "name": "Spain",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "en"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "PT",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "preSelection": 351,
            "currencySign": "€",
            "translations": [
                {
                    "id": "24",
                    "name": "Portugal",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "en"
                },
                {
                    "id": "17",
                    "name": "Portugal",
                    "text": null,
                    "languageId": "de"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

Ok that worked!
But now I want to sort my countries objects by the collected translations Objects based on their german names:

```
http://localhost:8090/countries?translations.languages.id=de&sort=translations.name
```

The result is:

```
 [
    {
        "id": "DE",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 49,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Deutschland",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            },
            {
                "id": "322",
                "name": "Allemagne",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "fr"
            },
            {
                "id": "18",
                "name": "Germany",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "DE",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 49,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Deutschland",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            },
            {
                "id": "322",
                "name": "Allemagne",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "fr"
            },
            {
                "id": "18",
                "name": "Germany",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "DE",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 49,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Deutschland",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            },
            {
                "id": "322",
                "name": "Allemagne",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "fr"
            },
            {
                "id": "18",
                "name": "Germany",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "PT",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 351,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "24",
                "name": "Portugal",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            },
            {
                "id": "17",
                "name": "Portugal",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "PT",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 351,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "24",
                "name": "Portugal",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            },
            {
                "id": "17",
                "name": "Portugal",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ES",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 34,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "16",
                "name": "Spanien",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            },
            {
                "id": "23",
                "name": "Spain",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ES",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "preSelection": 34,
        "currencySign": "€",
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": "16",
                "name": "Spanien",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "de"
            },
            {
                "id": "23",
                "name": "Spain",
                "text": null,
                "languageId": "en"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Well that did not worked! Is there any possibility to get that working?

Thanks in advance for every response.